# How to get previous page route in Symfony?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I am looking for way to do this in 'right' symfony way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a way to get the referer page from the $request variable. For example, if I was in *myaction/mypage* and click to *myaction2/mypage2* by this **getReferer()** method I get 'http://myweb/myaction/mypage'.

If you are in an action method this can be done by

```
public function executeMyaction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   $previousUrl = $request->getReferer();
   ...
}
```

if you are somewhere else you can get the request by getting the conext

```
$previousUrl = $this->getContext()->getRequest()->getReferer();
```

For for sfWebRequest methods check the [sfWebRequest API](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWebRequest).

Note: this value could be inaccesible using proxy's

Comment: getReferer() will return full request url, but how to get route name of referer url??

Comment: sfWebRequest::getReferer() returns a HTTP_REFERER string not a route corresponding to it.