# Get the Referer name requested from http_request2 lib symfony1

Tags: php, ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.2

I have a query, as defined in the title, how to get the getReferer() functionality, when the called page is http_request call.

This url 
[How to get previous page route in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511768/how-to-get-previous-page-route-in-symfony) will work only when there is a page submit from previous page, then the $request->getReferer(); will get the value, But what if the previous page submit is a ajax call where in i will post only username, and the ajax call will respond with some code.

Requested:
How to Know the previous page URL When it is http_request call

Answer (score 0):

Use getPathInfoArray().

```
$pathinfo = $request->getPathInfoArray();
$referer = $pathinfo['HTTP_REFERER'];
```